# Unix command to check if a word exists then replace the word else leave as it is

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with multiple lines, I need to look for a word. If it exists then replace with another word, else leave it.

Input

```
Amount:{12},members:{2,state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}`enter code here`
Amount:{12},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
Amount:{10},members:{6,state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
```

If the line has word `members` then `,state:` should be replaced with `},state:` else if the word `members` is not present in the line then make no changes to the line.

Output

```
Amount:{12},members:{2},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
Amount:{12},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
Amount:{10},members:{6},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}`
```

I tried this `sed -i -e '/members/ s/,state/},state/; s/,state/,state'`

Thank you`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yes. I tried this sed -i -e '/members/ s/,state/},state/; s/,state/,state'

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` please try:

```
sed 's/\(members.*\)\(,state:\)/\1}\2/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes two passes, but does the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash

check=$(<input.txt)
match=",state:"
repl="},state:"
recheck="${check//$match/$repl}"
match="}}"
repl="}"
final="${recheck//$match/$repl}"
echo "${final}" > input2.txt
```

You can type it out directly on the command line, or make a .sh shell script and run it locally with

```
chmod +x fix_state.sh
./fix_state.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own try actually can work, just change a little to make it right:

```
$ cat file
Amount:{12},members:{2,state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}`enter code here`
Amount:{12},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
Amount:{10},members:{6,state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}

$ sed -e '/members/ s/,state/},state/;' file
Amount:{12},members:{2},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}`enter code here`
Amount:{12},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
Amount:{10},members:{6},state:{'xx'},city:{'yyyy'}
```

Or use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/,state/}.state/ if /members/' file
```

You can add `-i` switch to both of them when you are sure the results are what you want.
Add `-i` switch will change the input files inplace.